# Wordpress Uploads Permissions Issue

Tags: apache, wordpress, file-upload

I have a had a wordpress site up and running for over a month, and I have set that my uploads be organized by month/year.. When april was made the uploads stopped working.

The permissions on the wp-content and uploads are **775**, the permission of **04(folder)** was **747** and the owner was "apache" I've never run into this issue before on any wordpress site, how do I correct this for the future and fix the present issue?

I changed the organization option and I still can't upload.
The error is

> The uploaded file could not be moved
>   to
>   /var/www/vhosts/websitename.com/httpdocs/wp-content/uploads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you upload by FTP to that folder? It could be a problem of lack of disk space (or quota), specially if this is a shared hosting. But even in VPS or dedicated, sometimes the /tmp directory where PHP first uploads the files is mounted from a different filesystem than /var (where the apache vhost root is probably located). That **could** explain why you can upload it but not move it.